# What kind of statistical measure(s) could describe the deviation of positions from a circle?

Tags: statistics, circles, coordinate-systems

I need to find a statistical measure that describes the accuracy of my measurements.
Let's say I have a 2D printer and I want to draw a circle with it. I have theoretical coordinates where the plotter should be and measured values, where it actually is.
[image]

So I want to determine the accuracy of this 2D printer.
I calculate the Euclidean distance of the theoretical and measured coordinates.
What kind of statistical measure should I use to represent the accuracy of that 2D printing process. **I want some kind of percentage value that shows how accurate it is**. Could you suggest something?